# R: Data Layout of Factorial Design

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, indexing, statistics

I am trying to write the data layout of a s^k factorial design in R. So i started with the  smallest factorial design,that is, 2^2 design.

The data layout of a 2^2 factorial design is :

```
   00 10
   01 11
```

0 indicates low level while 1 indicates high level of a factor .

that is,  if i have two factors such as factor A and factor B then 10 indicates high level of factor A and low level of factor B.

So,
i tried to construct the data layout in R by the following commands :

```
  mat=matrix(0,nrow=2,ncol=2)

 for(i in 0:1){
   for(j in 0:1){
   mat[i,j] = c(i,j)
  # print(mat)
 }
```

}

I am realizing that the problem is within `mat[i, j] = c(i, j)` , particularly in `c(i,j)`.

i am not understanding how to handle it so that i would get the index of `mat` matrix as the element
in that position of the matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you need

```
expand.grid(FactorA = c("00", "10"), FactorB = c("00", "10"))
```